# Get all open user tasks for specified process instance in Camunda Zeebe

Tags: camunda, zeebe

I am using Camunda Zeebe 1.2.4 with Camunda Tasklist.

Camunda Tasklist API contains the GraphQL method to get user tasks for all process instances:
https://docs.camunda.io/docs/apis-clients/tasklist-api/queries/tasks

But I cant find the method to get tasks for concrete active process instance.

Is there a way to filter tasks by process instance id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *currently* not possible. I think you can filter for certain task types or assigned user, which covers most use cases. But we are open for feedback so please feel free to open a feature request via https://camunda.com/contact/ or the forum https://forum.camunda.io/ and describe your use case more in depth.